# Is there any way to spliit a jasper report Gantt chart vertically?

Tags: jasper-reports, gantt-chart

I am creating a Gantt chart with jasper reports. But in this chart think it as a calendar where we can see some resource allocations. So the resource is a task and the allocations are sub tasks. That means there are multiple sub tasks for a task that are spread through months. If my data set contains data that spreads through about 6 months of a time period then the Gantt is very crowded and the tick labels are overlapping with each other. BTW the ticks should be shown in days. I want to split this report into several pages say 3 months for a page. The sub tasks doesn't have to start and end in one page. It's ok to start in one page and end them in another. So I basically want to print one report and split it to pages. I'm new to Jasper reports. It would be great help if someone can help me with a solution. The chart is getting its data through a sub data set and the data source is a Json.

Thanks